# Unable to boot out of grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a laptop running Windows 10, and I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 and dual boot the two operating systems. After this my computer just booted into Ubuntu and I wasn't able to figure out how to boot into Windows.

I installed Boot-Repair ([Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary](https://paste2.org/f71tnL1b)), but now when I boot up my laptop it only boots to a grub> prompt and I am unsure what to do from here.

I currently put in a different hard drive that has a Windows 7 image so I could post this question, but what do I have to do in the grub menu to be able to boot up either to Windows or Ubuntu?

Below is a photo of the grub> prompt I see when I boot my computer. Note that I am trying to boot from the hd0 partitions. The hd1 partitions are on the hard drive that I am currently using to boot Windows 7.

Results of `ls -all` from the `grub>` prompt:

[image]

Comment: If Windows 10 was pre-installed then it was UEFI. Did you also install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Your older Windows 7 install is probably BIOS boot mode. The two boot modes are incompatible, you must choose from UEFI which you want and then that install can only boot in that mode. Or once at grub menu you can only boot another install in same boot mode. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Here is the BootInfo summary report

http://paste2.org/f71tnL1b

Comment: Do not run auto fix from Boot-Repair. That installs grub to all MBRs, you want to keep Windows boot in MBR of sda, and Ubuntu/grub in sdc. All installs shown are in BIOS boot mode.   But your original install of Windows probably was UEFI since system is UEFI? And Boot-Repair says you may have Secure boot on. You cannot boot in CSM/BIOS mode with UEFI secure boot on.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. So my question is now how do I turn off secure boot and ultimately have my PC boot into Windows 10 again or just have it dual boot so I can use both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Since BIOS installs, you should just be able to select drive sda as boot to boot Windows. Secure Boot setting is in UEFI. Some systems may let you boot in BIOS mode if you have told it to boot that way even with default settings in UEFI/BIOS being different.

Comment: @oldfred These are total n00b questions but how do I select a drive to boot to Windows?

Comment: You should have that selection with UEFI/BIOS. Most UEFI have two keys for UEFI, one is to change UEFI configurations and default boot order. Often f2 used, but check your manual. And UEFI has a separate boot menu to override default or select flash drive. That often is f10 or f12 again your manual should say. Some like HP require two keys. HP to get into UEFI/BIOS menu - escape then f10 as soon as it starts.